# Issue when using CCFadeIn for multiline text label in COCS2D

Tags: multiline

I want to out multiline text in CCLabeTTF. It I am able. But I want that the text appeared smoothly. For this I use action CCFadeIn.
    $        //Multiline output description

```
    description =[descriptions valueForKey:@"text_MainHistory"];

    float fontSize =22;
    CGSize maxSize = {500, 400};
    CGSize actualSize = [description sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize containerSize = {actualSize.width, actualSize.height};
    descriptionText = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:description dimensions:containerSize alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:fontSize];
    descriptionText.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2);
    descriptionText.color = ccc3(128, 64, 0);
    [descriptionText runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:5.0f], nil]];
    [self addChild:descriptionText z:2];
```

But at performance for half-seconds appears and disappears text, and then begin CCFadeIn.

Where I am mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but it looks like you should have set the label's opacity to zero right after you set it's color.